# mmenu-js menu doesn't work until I load the page, turbolinks doesn't load the mmenu-js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-6, turbolinks, mmenu

I am facing an issue with turbolinks, I always have to refresh my page before the mmenu-js sidemenu works properply. Here my code:
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function(){

```
    // Mobile Mmenu
var $menu = $("nav#menu").mmenu({
    "extensions": ["pagedim-black"],
    counters: false,
    keyboardNavigation: {
        enable: true,
        enhance: true
    },
    navbar: {
        title: 'MENU'
    },
    navbars: [{position:'bottom',content: ['<a href="#0">© 2020 Azalearn</a>']}]}, 
    {
    // configuration
    clone: true,
    classNames: {
        fixedElements: {
            fixed: "menu_2",
            sticky: "sticky"
        }
    }
});
var $icon = $("#hamburger");
var API = $menu.data("mmenu");
$icon.on("click", function () {
    API.open();
});
API.bind("open:finish", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $icon.addClass("is-active");
    }, 100);
});
API.bind("close:finish", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $icon.removeClass("is-active");
    }, 100);
});
```

);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are more mmenujs but there is an Turbolink wrapper:

```html
<script>
    document.addEventListener(
        "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            new Mmenu( "#my-menu", {
                wrappers: ["turbolinks"]
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

> What it does
>
> Using the "turbolinks" wrapper will enable the menu to be re-initiated after navigating to a new page "the turbolinks way".

https://mmenujs.com/docs/wrappers/turbolinks.html

If there is another mmenu you have to reset the menu state that your script hopefully provides:

```js
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:before-cache", function() {
  // something like
  $mmenu.destroy()
})
```

https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#preparing-the-page-to-be-cached